NSEntityDescription Error when trying to provide modelContainer to WindowGroup
I'm having an issue when trying to provide my model container to my WindowGroup. I get the error:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'TaskItem''

Not sure what the issue could be. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
TaskItem.swift:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class TaskItem: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var taskTitle: String
    var creationDate: Date
    var isCompleted: Bool
    var tint: String
    
    init(id: UUID = .init(), taskTitle: String, creationDate: Date = .init(), isCompleted: Bool = false, tint: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.taskTitle = taskTitle
        self.creationDate = creationDate
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
        self.tint = tint
    }
    
    var tintColor: Color {
        switch tint {
        case "TaskColor 1": return .taskColor1
        case "TaskColor 2": return .taskColor2
        case "TaskColor 3": return .taskColor3
        case "TaskColor 4": return .taskColor4
        case "TaskColor 5": return .taskColor5
        default: return .black
        }
    }
}

DIController.swift:
import Swinject
import Supabase

class DIContainer {
    static let shared = DIContainer()
    let container: Container

    private init() {
        container = Container()
    }

    func initializeDependencies() async {
        container.register(LoginViewModel.self) { resolver in
            LoginViewModel(supabaseClient: supabaseClient)
        }
    }
}

MyApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import Swinject
import SwiftData

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    init() {
        DIContainer.shared.initializeDependencies()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(DIContainer.shared.container.resolve(LoginViewModel.self)!)
                //.modelContainer(persistenceController.container)
                //.modelContainer(for: TaskItem.self)
        }
        //.modelContainer(for: TaskItem.self)
        .modelContainer(persistenceController.container)
    }
}

PersistenceController.swift
import SwiftData

class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: ModelContainer

    init() {
        // Initialize the ModelContainer with the TaskItem model
        container = try! ModelContainer(for: TaskItem.self)
    }
}


I can't reproduce but I left out the DIContainer so I assume that class is part of the issue.

@JoakimDanielson ahh I had a suspicion it might be something related to that but I'm not sure why since the DIContainer doesn't deal with the model at all.

Ok so I figured out the issue. It was because of another class I was using since I was trying to access a swiftUI model context outside of a view

Ok so I figured out the issue. It was because of another class TaskDataManager I was using since I was trying to access a swiftUI model context outside of a view.
The TaskDataManager class looked like this (simplified to the bare minimum:
class TaskDataManager: ObservableObject {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
}

It worked fine once I removed this class and added the insert/delete/update operations directly into the view like this:
Button(action: {
                let task = TaskItem(taskTitle: taskTitle, creationDate: taskDate, tint: taskColor)
                do {
                    context.insert(task)
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Create Task")
            })


Well you can’t use @Environment outside of a view
